# Numerous WHERE conditions mysql

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause

I have the following code that conducts what I want. However i need a second where condition where column Accepted in table projects is equal to yes. I dont know how i would enter this into my current join as the where is for the user table.

```
$query_Name = "SELECT u.Student_Surname, u.Student_Forename, Project_Title, Project_id
FROM users u
INNER JOIN projects p2 ON u.id = p2.Project_Lecturer
INNER JOIN project_course pc ON p2.Project_id = pc.Proj_id
INNER JOIN courses c ON pc.Cour_id = c.Course_id
INNER JOIN users u2 ON c.Code = u2.Course
WHERE u2.Username = ".$_SESSION['MM_Username']." 
ORDER BY Project_id ASC" ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query_Name = "SELECT u.Student_Surname, u.Student_Forename, Project_Title, Project_id  
 FROM users u
 INNER JOIN projects p2 ON u.id = p2.Project_Lecturer
 INNER JOIN project_course pc ON p2.Project_id = pc.Proj_id
 INNER JOIN courses c ON pc.Cour_id = c.Course_id
 INNER JOIN users u2 ON c.Code = u2.Course
 WHERE u2.Username = ".$_SESSION['MM_Username']." AND p2.Accepted = 'yes'
 ORDER BY Project_id ASC" ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE u2.Username = ".$_SESSION['MM_Username']."  AND p2.Accepted = 'yes'
```

Or you could use

```
INNER JOIN projects p2 ON u.id = p2.Project_Lecturer AND p2.Accepted = 'yes'
```

Second alternative could be faster, depends on other things though

Answer (score 0):

The WHERE is actually for all the joined tables, hence you say explicitly which tables you are using on the WHERE clause, otherwise the query won't work if it is ambiguous.

So, you use:

```
WHERE
u2.Username = ".$_SESSION['MM_Username']." -- this is for the u2 table
AND
p2.Accepted = 'yes' -- this is for p2 table
```

You simply use the AND to add more logic here. So, the whole query would be:

```
$query_Name = "SELECT u.Student_Surname, u.Student_Forename, Project_Title, Project_id  
 FROM users u
 INNER JOIN projects p2 ON u.id = p2.Project_Lecturer
 INNER JOIN project_course pc ON p2.Project_id = pc.Proj_id
 INNER JOIN courses c ON pc.Cour_id = c.Course_id
 INNER JOIN users u2 ON c.Code = u2.Course
 WHERE u2.Username = ".$_SESSION['MM_Username']." AND p2.Accepted = 'yes'
 ORDER BY Project_id ASC" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `AND` operator in your where clause.

```
$query_Name = "SELECT u.Student_Surname, 
                      u.Student_Forename, 
                      Project_Title, 
                      Project_id  
               FROM users u INNER JOIN projects p2 
                       ON u.id = p2.Project_Lecturer
                    INNER JOIN project_course pc 
                       ON p2.Project_id = pc.Proj_id
                    INNER JOIN courses c 
                       ON pc.Cour_id = c.Course_id
                    INNER JOIN users u2 ON c.Code = u2.Course
               WHERE u2.Username = ".$_SESSION['MM_Username']." 
                     AND p2.Accepted = 'yes'
               ORDER BY Project_id ASC" ;
```